# how to know if url path contains some string

Tags: javascript

I may have the following urls:

```
localhost/mysite
localhost/mysite/index.php
localhost/mysite/#hashstring
localhost/mysite/index.php/#hasstring
localhost/mystie/index.php/path
localhost/mysite/index.php/path#hashstring
localhost/mystie/index.php/someotherpath
```

So in the above urls I want to check if there is some path string after index.php. So `/index.php/path, /index.php/path#hashstring, and index.php/someotherpath` should **return true** but other urls should **return false.**

Comment: Those URL's aren't valid, because they're missing a scheme.

Comment: `/\/index\.php\/[^#]+/`

Answer (score -1):

Try this way:

```
function check(){
 var str = "localhost/mysite/index.php/#hasstring";
 var flag = false;
 var idx = str.indexOf("index.php/");]
 var length = str.length; 
 if( idx >= 0 && length > idx){
   flag = true
 }
 return flag
```

}